# Ensuring a transaction within a method with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, rails-activerecord

I have a situation in which I would like a method to  work within a transaction, but only if a transaction has not already been started. Here's a contrived example to distill what I'm talking about:

```
class ConductBusinessLogic
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def process!
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      ModelA.create_multiple(params[:model_a])
      ModelB.create_multiple(params[:model_a])
    end
  end
end

class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_multiple(params)
    # I'd like the below to be more like "ensure_transaction"
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      params.each { |p| create(p) }
    end
  end
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_multiple(params)
    # Again, a transaction here is only necessary if one has not already been started
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      params.each { |p| create(p) }
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, I don't want these to act as nested transactions. I want the `.create_multiple` methods to only start transactions if they are not already called within a transaction, such as through `ConductBusinessLogic#process!`. If the model methods are called by themselves, they should start their own transaction, but if they are already being called inside a transaction, as through `ConductBusinessLogic#process!`, they should not nest a sub-transaction.

I don't know of a way in which Rails provides this out of the box. If I run the above code as-is and a rollback is triggered by one of the model methods, the whole transaction will still go through because the sub-transaction swallows the `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception. If I use the `requires_new` option on the sub-transactions, savepoints will be used to simulate nested transactions, and only that sub-transaction will actually be rolled back. The behavior I would like would be something to the effect of `ActiveRecord::Base.ensure_transaction`, such that a new transaction is started only if there isn't already an outer transaction, so that any sub-transaction can trigger a rollback on the entire outer transaction. This would allow these methods to be transactional on their own, but defer to a parent transaction if there is one.

Is there a built-in way to achieve this behavior, and if not, is there a gem or patch that will work?

Comment: What about [transaction_open](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-transaction_open-3F)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just adding a `create_multiple_without_transaction` method to your `ModelA` and `ModelB` classes? which would look something like this:

```
class ConductBusinessLogic
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def process!
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      ModelA.create_multiple_without_transaction(params[:model_a])
      ModelB.create_multiple_without_transaction(params[:model_a])
    end
  end
end

class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_multiple(params)
    # I'd like the below to be more like "ensure_transaction"
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.create_multiple_without_transaction(params)
    end
  end

  def self.create_multiple_without_transaction(params)
    params.each { |p| create(p) }
  end
end
```

then your regular `create_multiple` would work as before, but for cases were you don't need a transaction you would just call `create_multiple_without_transaction`